# How do I dump the memory of running process in Windows?

Tags: memory, gdb

I am learning how to use GDB. I want to dump the memory of a running process. I tried to like this

```sh
gdb -pid 2767

(gdb) gcore test.dmp
warning: cannot close "test.dmp": Invalid operation
Can't create a corefile
```

I am new to GDB, how can I dump the memory of a running process in Windows using GDB?

Comment: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html

Comment: How do I get the start and end address for a process?